# how to add a default option to an angular drop down box

Tags: angular

**Background Info**

I need to modify an existing drop down component that is populated from a database, to add an "All locations" option.  We do not want to add this to the db, but just include in the list of options - as the first item.

I am not an angular developer and so I'm a little lost on how to accomplish this:

**Code**

From what I can tell, the drop down is created from logic inside a location-options.component.ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-location-options',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="parentForm">
      <ptrn-field label="{{ title }}" emptyLabel="None specified" class="grid__item {{ fieldClass }}">
        <select
          class="field__select field__select--grow"
          #options
          (change)="setValueChanged(options.value)"
          formControlName="locationSelected"
        >
          <option
            class="field__option"
            *ngFor="let location of locationOptions"
            [value]="location.locationCode"
            [id]="location.id"
            [selected]="optionSelected === location.locationCode"
          >
            {{ location.locationCode }}
          </option>
        </select>
        <ptrn-field-error name="required">Please enter a description.</ptrn-field-error>
      </ptrn-field>
    </form>
  `,
  styles: [],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ways you can do it.

Simple solution would be :

Write an option tag wth default value just before the option tag doing ngFor.

```
<select
      class="field__select field__select--grow"
      #options
      (change)="setValueChanged(options.value)"
      formControlName="locationSelected"
    >
      <option value="">
          All locations
      </option>
      <option
        class="field__option"
        *ngFor="let location of locationOptions"
        [value]="location.locationCode"
        [id]="location.id"
        [selected]="optionSelected === location.locationCode"
      >
        {{ location.locationCode }}
      </option>
    </select>
```

Then there are crazy ways like add an rxjs pipe to modify api response to add default option or you can create a custom pipe that modifies locationOptions.

It's up to you.